# Android Tap Device Sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager, gesturelistener

is there a sensor in android to detect a tap on the device? I have a service and I want to detect when the user touches the phone. He can touch(tap) the screen, back or any other part of the device and it will trigger a function within my service. Is that possible? For example, if I have the device in my pocket, and I want my service to call a certain function when the user tap the phone from outside his pocket. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accelerometer.  The accelerometer detects a force on the device, and a tap would cause a force.  The trick would be filtering out other forces, such as bouncing when walking.

Comment: how do I differentiate the difference since walking or other motion will cause the accelerometer to behave the same way.

Comment: Look for other sources of input to help do that, or for characteristics of the force from a tap that are different from other sources.  THe gyroscope may help to distinguish movement (movement would tend to have some roation vector I'd think).  But there isn't a quick answer here, its more of a research project that anything else.